# Methods of setting breakpoints on specific lines in R

Tags: r, breakpoints

I have a file, `test.R`

```
a <- 5+9
b <- a+10
c <- b+42
```

If I start R from the command line and try `setBreakpoint(srcfile="test.R", line=2)`, I get the error : `No source refs found.`

The documentation for `setBreakpoint` leads me to believe that `setBreakpoint` is only intended for setting breakpoints at function declarations.

QUESTION : Is there a way to set a breakpoint at a particular line number  within a file, when running R from the command line?

Comment: A somewhat brutisch approach would be to put a `browser()` at the line you want the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for a solution that would not require rerunning the script each time I want to change the breakpoint location.

Comment: You can also use RStudio to set breakpoints, but this does not run on a terminal...